# How to default to command line interface vim

Tags: vim, command-line-interface, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to use the command line vim. Now, whenever I type `vim`, the GUI application starts – not the command line version. **How can I default to the command line `vim`?**

Comment: What does it output if you try `$ which --all vim` and `$ alias vim` in the console? Maybe `vim` is a link to `gvim`, or an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to install it again, and it worked this time.

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Thanks for your time